# Javascript storing a value as a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an html form that makes calculations based off of user input.

This is the code I have right now:

```
<form name="testing">
<table border="1" style="padding: 5px;">
<tr>
    <td>Ingredient Name</td>
    <td>Amount (in Mg)</td>
    <td>% Carrier</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Total Carrier Volume</td>
    <td>Total Ingredient Volume</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="a"> Mg</input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="b"></input> %</td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate Final Volume</button></td>
    <td id="c"></td>
    <td id="d"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

With the following javascript:

```
<script>
function calculate() {
    var volume = document.testing.a.value;
    var carrier = document.testing.b.value;
    var mCarrier = carrier/100;

    var x = document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = mCarrier*(volume/(1-mCarrier));
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = volume + x;
}
</script>
```

You can also see it here:  www.healthkismet.com/supplement_pricer.html

Right now the line:

```
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = volume + x
```

evaluates to string + x, but I am not sure why.  If I do calculations with just x then everything is okay.

I think the way I'm storing the variables 'volume' and 'carrier' is the root cause but I don't know why.  (and the 'x' variable is computed as an integer because it's already been divided and multiplied).

I've looked at this answer on stackexchange: [Addition is not working in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377410/addition-is-not-working-in-javascript) and understand how to hack around it.

I've also seen this answer: [take user input from a Form perform calculation (order of operations) and output back into that form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306784/take-user-input-from-a-form-perform-calculation-order-of-operations-and-output) but if I just typed that example in verbatim I wouldn't know exactly why my code doesn't work right now as it is.

Comment: Hi can you type check the values of volume and carrier??

Comment: You can use parseInt()/parseFloat() if you want the value as a number type.

Comment: Yes we can use this option but let us try to understand why is there a need to do this when the type="number" is already specified..!!

Comment: This question has been asked and answered about a dozen times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841373/how-to-force-js-to-do-math-instead-of-putting-two-strings-together, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614374/plus-arithmetic-operation, etc.

Comment: @MixedVeg - Specifying the `type="number"` attribute only affects how the browser renders the input field. It doesn't change the data type returned by the `.value` property, which remains a `string` in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
var volume = parseInt(document.testing.a.value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/st2y7agy/

Answer (score 0):

It is because your value of `volume` variable is treated as `String` values.
If you check the data type of the variable `volume` it show `String` by using JavaScript function [typeof volume](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

In your code It will convert your expression `volume + x` as `String + Number` which gives wrong answer as this will result in concatenate both as string.

[From this reference Doc](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) `Adding two numbers, will return the sum, but adding a number and a string will return a string:`

**EDIT:**

May [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29) will help to understand concept of `<input type="number" ../>`