# Javascript basics: change operator value depending on retrieved value

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm a Javascript newbie and I am creating a calculator that fetches doctor fees for a direct care provider. I got help creating a script by referencing BBog's answer on this thread:

[take user input from a Form perform calculation (order of operations) and output back into that form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306784/take-user-input-from-a-form-perform-calculation-order-of-operations-and-output)

I succeeded in gathering the sum of various input values and multiplying them by varying dollar amounts per input in order to arrive at a total price. I even managed to tweak it so that the price charged per child changed if their were no adults.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to change the per child fee depending on how many children are being added. First two are supposed to be $25 each, while additional child are supposed to be $10, e.g. $25 for 1, $50 for 2, $60 for 3, $70 for 4 etc. Everything I've tried along those lines draws a syntax error, and I am having hard time figuring out how to phrase the question in order to get an answer via Google.

Here's my code so far:

```
function calculate() {
var adult1 = document.DPCcalculator.adult20to44.value * 55;
var adult2 = document.DPCcalculator.adult45to64.value * 75;
var adult3 = document.DPCcalculator.adult65.value * 95;
var childvalue = document.DPCcalculator.child.value;    
var child2 = document.DPCcalculator.child19to22.value * 30;
if (childvalue <= 2); {
    (child1 = document.DPCcalculator.child.value * 25);
}

// here's what I don't know how to fix
// if (childvalue > 2); {
    // (child1 = childvalue > 2 * 10 + 50);
// }

if (adult1 + adult2 + adult3 === 0) {
    (child1 = document.DPCcalculator.child.value * 70);
}

result = (adult1 + adult2 + adult3 + child1 + child2);
document.DPCcalculator.output.value = result;
}
```

Everything works except the conditional stuff for cost per child that I mentioned above. I've got the 2 children or less code working, but haven't figured out how to throw something different to 3rd child and up. I've tried several approaches, so what's there presently is just one of my shots in the dark.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the Javascript exchange. Things seem to have got a lot user-friendly in the interface, since I've never had that problem before. I posted the Q from the page where all the javascript latest questions were appearing, which seemed logical. 

Thanks so much for the down vote, it really makes things better.

Comment: Technical questions belong on StackOverflow. Anyway, the part you have trouble could simply be `child1 = (childvalue - 2) * 10 + 50`. This would work though the whole thing isn't exactly beautiful code.

Comment: PS: It's some kind of habit here to downvote questions that are off topic. There was some big kind of discussion about it on META and for whatever reasons it's encouraged to do so. Just ignore it, it's kind of childish (I think it's to get off topic questions away from the front page or something)

Comment: Thorsten, thanks for your comment. I tried implementing your code a couple different ways, but for some odd reason it seems to be adding $30 to the first adult value, even if children = 0. Then if I have an adult, it adds each child at $10 each, including the first 2. So I'm missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a quick check seems to indicate that I've solved this with a switch:

```
switch (true)
    { case childvalue <= 2:
        child1 = childvalue * 25;
        break;
        case childvalue > 2:
        child1 = childvalue * 10 + 30;
    }
```

Will play around to be double-sure that works, but right now it looks like the solution.

I guess it's a cheat in a way, but I decided it was simpler to multiply everything by 10 and then add 30 to make the first two children add up to $50 than to try to isolate children 1 and 2 from children 3+. It gets the same result with less complication.